# load() triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used `off()` for the modal but the `alert` is firing multiple times the second time the modal triggered, any ideas why this is happening and how I can stop it?

```
$('#my_modal').modal('show').off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#head').load('example.com/email.html', function(){
        $.getScript('jquery.min.js', function(data){
            alert('debug');
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: how is the event triggered?

Comment: `.off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal',...);` suggests that you'd have better to delegate event. Anyway, your code with provided context doesn't really make sense, why would you re-include jQuery on page?

Comment: @A.Wolff that just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your you have bound `.on('shown.bs.modal'` it will be fired everytime your modal loads.

If you want to unbind it after the first showing, try this:

```
$('#my_modal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#my_modal').off('shown.bs.modal'); // might be able to use $(this).off('shown.bs.modal');
  $('#head').load('example.com/email.html', function(){
    $.getScript('jquery.min.js', function(data){
        alert('debug');
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: In this case, use `one` not `on`: `.one('shown.bs.modal', handler);` instead